# Proving the solution of an ODE exists for $t \geq 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the system
$$x'(t) = y(t)$$
$$y'(t) = -y(t)^3-p(x(t)),$$
where $p(x(t))$ is a polynomial of odd degree whose leading coefficient is positive. I'm interested in proving that the solution exists for all $t \geq 0$. I was thinking of using the Lyapunov function $L(x,y)= \frac{1}{2}y^2+P(x)$, where $P(x)$ is the antiderivative of $p(x)$. However, I'm not sure how to prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there any constraints on the initial value?

Comment: @JPMarciano Not really, just that $(x(0),y(0)) = (x_0,y_0)$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function
$$
V(x,y)=P(x)+\frac12 y^2,
$$
where $P(x)$ is the antiderivative of $p(x)$ such that (to be specific) $P(0)=0$. $P(x)$  is a polynomial of even degree whose leading coefficient is positive, thus,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} P(x)=+\infty,
$$
thus,
$$
\lim_{\|(x,y)\|\to\infty} V(x,y)=+\infty.
$$

The only posibility for the solution of the system to not exist is to go to infinity. Suppose that there exists some solution $(x(t),y(t))$ such that
$$
\lim_{t\to A} \|(x(t),y(t))\|=+\infty,
$$ where $A$ is some finite number or $+\infty$. This implies that for this solution
$$
\lim_{t\to A} V(x(t),y(t))=+\infty.
$$
But this is impossible because
$$
\frac{d}{dt}V(x(t),y(t))= p(x(t))y-y^4(t)-p(x(t))y=-y^4(t)\le 0,
$$
thus, $V(x(t),y(t))$ is nonincreasing.
This also proves that all solutions of the system are bounded.

Comment: +1. Beautiful solution.